# set ItemContainerStyle from code

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am working on a custom wpf control which is derived from a ListBox and am trying to apply some formatting to a custom property.
When a particular custom property is false, I want to apply some formatting to the ListBox.
I am using the following code to attempt to apply the styling -

```
var t = new Trigger();                

var BackgroundSetter = new Setter {Property = BackgroundProperty, Value = null};
var BrushSetter = new Setter { Property = BorderBrushProperty, Value = null };

t.Setters.Add(BackgroundSetter);
t.Setters.Add(BrushSetter);

var s = new Style(typeof(ListBox));
s.Triggers.Add(t);

editor.ItemContainerStyle.Triggers.Add(t);
```

I have also tried the following with no luck -

```
editor.ItemContainerStyle = s;
```

I am getting an error that indicates that some object was not initialized and stepping through shows that editor.ItemContainerStyle is null.
The actual error message just says Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: if `editor.ItemContainerStyle` is null, calling `editor.ItemContainerStyle.Triggers.Add(t)` is somewhat problematic...

Comment: Yes - but how can I initialize ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: Maybe something like `editor.ItemContainerStyle = new Style()` ?

Comment: I tried that in various ways, but still no luck.

Comment: Try to define the Style somewhere in xaml within default style for your element, then find it in code and apply. By the way, no need to do it in code - just set this property for your element in it's default style and apply this property using TemplateBinding

Comment: I could get the intended functionality using template binding, but it is a custom control that will be used often and I would like to  build in the functionality into the coding of the custom control.  That is why I am taking this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working - below is the code that I actually ended up using -

```
public bool IsSelectable
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectableProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsSelectableProperty, value); }
}

public static DependencyProperty IsSelectableProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelectable", typeof(bool), typeof(ListEditor), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, new PropertyChangedCallback(IsSelectablePropertyChanged)) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });

private static void IsSelectablePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var editor = sender as ListEditor;

    var s = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));                
    var enableSetter = new Setter {Property = IsEnabledProperty, Value = editor.IsSelectable};
    s.Setters.Add(enableSetter);

    editor.ItemContainerStyle = s;                                       
}
```